# SoapUI hanging on Jenkins after couple steps

Tags: jenkins, cmd, soapui

So, I have installed SoapUI on Jenkins slave *SLAVE1* machine and successfully launched all tests in my project using following command:

```
C:\Path_to_bin\testrunner.bat -f"C:\where_to_put_reports\reports" -I -A "C:\SoapUI\projects\project_name.xml"
```

In the meantime, I've also accepted sharing some anonymous data so that the prompt no longer interrupts me. All this was done via RDC under some USER1

Next, I've created a Jenkins job, restricted running to that particular slave and added Windows Batch step there, **pretty the same as above.**

My assumption was that it should run with no problem.

What I've got was:

```
C:\Jenkins\workspace\project_name>C:\Path_to_bin\testrunner.bat -f"C:\where_to_put_reports\reports" -I -A "C:\SoapUI\projects\project_name.xml" 
16:25:42,902 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [C:\soapui-settings.xml]

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
16:25:48,952 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 12 ms
16:25:48,952 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
```

And nothing more, since it seems to be hanging forever with no effect.
Adding `start` or `call` before the batch command gives no positive effect.

**FYI:** Jenkins is running tests under another user, not the one I was logging in with.

So, what could be the source of issue or fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually I should've been reading logs carefully.

First of all, for some reason, when launched w/ Jenkins, SoapUI wants to create `soapui-settings.xml` file:

> Creating new settings at [C:\soapui-settings.xml]

Which is not even overriden using `-t` key, which is strange, but whatever. [SoapUI CLI args](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html)

Instead, I used ant as described [HERE](http://paste.plurk.com/show/848526/). In fact, it does pretty the same as `testrunner.bat` + user args.

In the first try, it also gave no effect, now I had the same log:

> Creating new settings at [C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\soapui-settings.xml]

So I came with the idea to manually place `soapui-settings.xml` in `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\` and it worked:

> [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\soapui-settings.xml]

Actually, I did not try placing the settings file to `C:\soapui-settings.xml` (as when launching using Win Batch step), but I believe it should also work.

**Note that this is a workaround.**

Comment: I tried to put manually the file in C:\soapui-settings.xml using a Win Batch step, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you do "start" then you need to add double quotes right after the command so it would look something like:

```
start "" "C:\Path_to_bin\testrunner.bat" -f"C:\where_to_put_reports\reports" -I -A "C:\SoapUI\projects\project_name.xml"
```

It will run the command in the background.
But if you need to artifact test results with jenkins, then running them in the bg is not the best idea. On the other hand you could always add some whaiter, e.g.:

```
timeout /t %timeout_seconds% /nobreak
```

Also, posting your testrunner.bat could help to define the problem.